# How to match multiple files with names using TextIO.Read in Cloud Dataflow

Tags: scala, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I have a gcs folder as below:

```
gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt=2017-12-01/part-0000.tsv
                                /dt=2017-12-02/part-0000.tsv
                                /dt=2017-12-03/part-0000.tsv
                                /dt=2017-12-04/part-0000.tsv
                                ...
```

I want to match only the files under `dt=2017-12-02` and `dt=2017-12-03` using `sc.textFile()` in Scio, which uses `TextIO.Read.from()` underneath as far as I know.

I've tried

```
gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt={2017-12-02,2017-12-03}/*.tsv
```

and

```
gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt=2017-12-(02|03)/*.tsv
```

Both match zero files:

```
INFO org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource - Filepattern gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt={2017-12-02,2017-12-03}/*.tsv matched 0 files with total size 0

INFO org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource - Filepattern gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt=2017-12-(02|03)/*.tsv matched 0 files with total size 0
```

What should be the valid filepattern on doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `TextIO.readAll()` transform that reads a `PCollection<String>` of filepatterns. Create the collection of filepatterns either explicitly via `Create.of()` or you can compute it using a `ParDo`.

```
case class ReadPaths(paths: java.lang.Iterable[String]) extends PTransform[PBegin, PCollection[String]] {
  override def expand(input: PBegin) = {
    Create.of(paths).expand(input).apply(TextIO.readAll())
  }
}

val paths = Seq(
  "gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt=2017-07-01/part-0000.tsv",
  "gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt=2017-12-20/part-0000.tsv",
  "gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt=2018-03-29/part-0000.tsv",
  "gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/dt=2018-05-04/part-0000.tsv"
)

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

sc.customInput("Read Paths", ReadPaths(paths.asJava))
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
gs://bucket/folder/dt=2017-12-0[12]/*.tsv
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames

Comment: I have not tried it myself but this seems the right syntax for what @pishen is attempting.

Comment: hmmm, sorry I didn't describe it well. I know `[]` can handle single char, but what I want is a general OR syntax. For example, if I want to match `2017-12-01` and `2017-12-20`, I can't use `[]` to match it.

Comment: I don't believe there is any OR functionality in the URI wildcard syntax for GCS. You'll have to be explicit about specifying full GCS directories.